# Creating a cronjob through script

Tags: shell, cron

Is there any way to create a cronjob in an automated way (script)?

The only way i know how to create a cronjob is through `contab -e` which creates a temporary conf file that is, once modified and exited, merged with the actual conf file in /var/spool/cron/crontabs (this file can't be modified directly).

In particular what i'm trying to do is package a script that needs to be run every minute. When the user installs the package, the cronjob needs to be added and there in lies my problem.

So:
I need a script to create a script that runs my script, not that confusing right? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
crontab filename
```

to install `filename` as the user's crontab. So your script can do something like:

```
crontab -l > crontab.txt # Get current crontab
echo "0 12 * * * /path/to/script" >>crontab.txt #Add a new entry
crontab crontab.txt # install new crontab
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. I had no idea you could specify a "template" crontab file as an argument for the program. And your solution for compatibility with already existing jobs was a bonus. Thanks alot :)

Comment: When you're wondering how to do things, don't you look at man pages?

Comment: I am also looking for the same but instead of txt file can I use csv?

Comment: @subhro The format of a crontab file is pretty specific, it's not a CSV file. You could write a script that converts a CSV file to crontab format.